# Insert variable in a string, matlab

Tags: matlab

I am analyzing some data and I need to load the information from a file. I wrote a script which contains the following line:

```
load('../Psychopy/DataPrueba/Estefi_1_datos.mat');
```

I'm wondering if there's anyway to write something like:

```
Name=Estefi;
load('../Psychopy/DataPrueba/Name_1_datos.mat');
```

Because it's data from an experiment, I have to do with 40 people at least and that little change in the script would automatize my work quite a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
Name='Estefi'; 
load(['../Psychopy/DataPrueba/',Name,'_1_datos.mat']);
```

Two things to note:

1. The variable `Name` has to be a string (use `'`)
2. You have to use square brackets (`[]`) around the combination of strings and your variable.

Comment: @Estefania posted it as an official answer, in case you want to accept.

Comment: @Estefania you can accept an answer by clicking on the check-mark below the voting buttons to the left.